IIS server crashing

We make ajax call to asmx web service, which internally calls async api method, synchronised using GetAwaiter().GetResult().
IIS is crashing consistently, analysing dump file, provided below summary,
Threads waiting in Monitor.Wait  are actually waiting to re-acquire a lock which they released. The signal to reacquire the lock will be given by a call to Monitor.Pulse or Monitor.PulseAll or when the timeout is hit.
Look at the callstack of the thread to see which function is making a call to Monitor.Wait and then review code to find out the function which is supposed to call Monitor.Pulse or Monitor.PulseAll and see why that function is not getting called.
and
win32u!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+14
user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+1e
VsLog!VSResponsiveness::Detours::DetourMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+6e
msenv!CMsoCMHandler::EnvironmentMsgLoop+205
msenv!CMsoCMHandler::FPushMessageLoop+6e
msenv!SCM::FPushMessageLoop+105
msenv!SCM_MsoCompMgr::FPushMessageLoop+3f
msenv!CMsoComponent::PushMsgLoop+3d
msenv!VStudioMainLogged+991
msenv!VStudioMain+8c
devenv!util_CallVsMain+5c
devenv!CDevEnvAppId::Run+1e3e
devenv!WinMain+d0
devenv!__scrt_common_main_seh+106
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+10
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+2b
Looking at parallel processes in visual studo, its clear there are 2 threads!! one of which is crashing IIS.
event viewer logs provided below error details,
A Webhost unhandled exception occurred.
Sender Information: System.AppDomain/35662677
Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at
System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallb
ack callback, Object state)
at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext,
ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,
ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWork
Item()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
Process Name: w3wp
Process ID: 9416
